Customize response from AWS API Gateway integrated to SQS
I have integrated AWS API Gateway to SQS queue and it give response in format
{
"SendMessageResponse": {
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "RequestId": "acfa1737-7d53-5aeb-8c75-482a8f8eab1b"
    },
    "SendMessageResult": {
        "MD5OfMessageAttributes": null,
        "MD5OfMessageBody": "ed1dbe6fa17bf45a3d20ea7be2661bfb",
        "MD5OfMessageSystemAttributes": null,
        "MessageId": "e41f656e-1e2a-4269-a0e0-2016d9406ac8",
        "SequenceNumber": null
    }
}

}
how can I customize the integraion that response will look like
{           
   "RequestId": "e41f656e-1e2a-4269-a0e0-2016d9406ac8",
   "Message": "Request Accepted"
}

where RequestId is MessageId from SQS Queue
and the Message is some custom acknowledgment message

Found a solution to use mapping response templates


The quickest way to implement this is to use a custom ResponseTemplate in API Gateway Integration response. Something like this.
       {
        "RequestId": $input.json('$.SendMessageResponse.ResponseMetadata.RequestId'),
        "Message": "Request Accepted"
       }

Also don't forget to re-deploy the API Gateway after updating the ResponseTemplate mapping.

